# "UIOP" package does not exist in SBCL, can someone help me to find?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I wondered whether you could help with an error I'm getting with SBCL. I'm doing a tutorial, and one of the first lessons is to load a script into LISP. Here's the script, called hello.lisp:

```
(defun hello ()    
      "say hello to USER"    
      (format t "hello ~a" (uiop:getenv "USER")))    
(hello)
```

But when I run the command: (load "hello.lisp") I get the following error:

```
debugger invoked on a SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1000510083}>:
  READ error during LOAD:

    Package UIOP does not exist.

      Line: 3, Column: 36, File-Position: 74

      Stream: #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /home/oliver/Programs/hello.lisp" {10015403F3}>

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Abort loading file "/home/oliver/Programs/hello.lisp".
  1:         Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-C:COMPILER-ERROR SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD :CONDITION #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Package ~A does not exist." {1001542543}> :STREAM #<SB-INT:FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /home/oliver/Programs/hello.lisp" {10015403F3}>)
```

Any ideas on how I can fix? It seems I'm missing "UIOP" but I can't figure out how to install. Thanks in advance!

Oliver

Comment: Is the tutorial publicly accessible? maybe if it is not directly reproducible or clear the author would like to update the tutorial

Comment: @coredump The tutorial is the 2nd video of my Udemy course, not publicly accessible. We discuss this issue at the minute 5'32, when we run sbcl with the `--script` flag, but I added a note in the video the first time we call uiop:getenv. [GitHub presentation](https://github.com/vindarel/common-lisp-course-in-videos/).

Comment: @Ehvince great!

Answer (score 5):

```
(require :uiop)
```

it seems you're using the `--script` option of sbcl which makes sbcl not load some stuff like asdf, uiop, etc.

Comment: Thank you! How do I exit --script mode?

Comment: you don't, script mode is kind of --load but without loading some stuff. sbcl has some startup files that loads at start in order to configure/load systems and alike, --script avoids loading any startup file which makes sbcl not load fancy stuff. --script is an option given to the sbcl executable, like sbcl --script some-file.lisp

Comment: It makes sbcl load the file without loading startup files and exit instead of giving you a repl. If you use --load instead it will load startup files and when loaded that file will give you a repl. --script is an option in order to ease sbcl being used for scripting, you can also chain it with the --noinform option like sbcl --noinform --script some-file.lisp  this will prevent sbcl printing the banner it prints initially, load the file and exit then.

Comment: your last comment could be added to the answer to be a bit more complete

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION
Please! add this **(require :asdf)**  command line to .sbclrc file  It will work.

```
(require :asdf)
(defun hello ()
"say hello to USER"
(format t "hello ~a" (uiop:getenv "USER")))
(hello)
```

[my hello.lisp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecEBr.png)